# Python Hash Functions

Tags: python, hash

What is a good way of hashing a hierarchy (similar to a file structure) in python?

I could convert the whole hierarchy into a dotted string and then hash that, but is there a better (or more efficient) way of doing this without going back and forth all the time?

An example of a structure I might want to hash is:

```
a -> b1 -> c -> 1 -> d
a -> b2 -> c -> 2 -> d
a -> c -> 1 -> d
```

Comment: By hierarchy, do you mean a single file's list of path components, i.e. ["usr", "local", "test", "myfile"]?

Comment: Downmodding, question is very unclear and confusing.

Comment: added an example to make it a little clearer...

Comment: What does the "->" symbol mean in the example?  What actual Python data structure contains the source data that creates your hierarchy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have access to your hierarchy components as a tuple, just hash it - tuples are hashable. You may  not gain a lot over conversion to and from a delimited string, but it's a start.

If this doesn't help, perhaps you could provide more information about how you store the hierarchy/path information.

Comment: +1. python isn't javascript, dictionary keys can be more than just strings.  unfortunately, it's not Lua either, where keys can be _any_ value

Answer (score 4):

How do you want to access your hierarchy?

If you're always going to be checking for a full path, then as suggested, use a tuple:
eg:

```
>>> d["a","b1","c",1,"d"] = value
```

However, if you're going to be doing things like "quickly find all the items below "a -> b1", it may make more sense to store it as a nested hashtable (otherwise you must iterate through all items to find those you're intereted in).

For this, a defaultdict is probably the easiest way to store.  For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def new_dict(): return defaultdict(new_dict)
d = defaultdict(new_dict)

d["a"]["b1"]["c"][1]["d"] = "test"
d["a"]["b2"]["c"][2]["d"] = "test2"
d["a"]["c"][1]["d"] = "test3"

print d["a"]["c"][1]["d"]  # Prints test3
print d["a"].keys()        # Prints ["c", "b1", "b2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make any object hashable by implementing the [`__hash__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

So you can simply add a suitable `__hash__()` method to the objects storing your hierarchy, e.g. compute the hash recursively, etc.