# Python - Subtract a List of Dicts containing str, int, list keys from Another

Tags: python, list, dictionary, subtraction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - Subtract a list of dicts from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100731/python-subtract-a-list-of-dicts-from-another)

I'm interested in comparing multiple lists, taking the difference and iterating through that.

Both are list of dicts that contain the following keys:
'ssid' - str, 'bssid' - str, 'channel' - int, 'flags' - list, 'found' - bool

I've tried:

```
 list = list(set(networks_list).difference(missing_networks))
```

But I receive the error:

```
unhashable type 'dict'
```

My data structure looks like this:

```
list: [
    {'found': False, 'flags': ['WPA2-PSK-CCMP', 'WPS', 'ESS'], 'ssid': 'SOHO_BROADCAST', 'bssid': '30:46:9a:9d:11:1a', 'channel': 1},
    {'found': False, 'flags': ['WPA-EAP-TKIP', 'WPA2-EAP-CCMP', 'ESS'], 'ssid': 'Cisco 2.4ghz', 'bssid': '40:f4:ec:7f:3c:5a', 'channel': 11},
    {'found': False, 'flags': ['WPA-EAP-TKIP', 'WPA2-EAP-CCMP', 'ESS'], 'ssid': 'Cisco 5.0ghz', 'bssid': '40:f4:ec:7f:3c:54', 'channel': 149}
]
```

Missing networks is initially empty.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks,

Parth