# 'Isomorphic' comparison of NetworkX Graph objects instead of the default 'address' comparison

Tags: python, hash, networkx, isomorphism

I would like to use NetworkX `Graph` objects as keys in a Python `dict`. However, I do not want the default behavior for comparison (i.e., by the address of the object). Instead, I would like isomorphic graphs to refer to be keys to the same elements in the `dict`.

Is this behavior already implemented somewhere? I could not find any information in this direction.

If I have to implement it myself, is the following assessment realistic?

- Wrap `networkx.Graph` in a class.
- Define `__eq__` such that it calls `is_isomorphic`.
- Define `__hash__` somehow (suggestions welcomed).

I think that I would have to make this wrapped Graph immutable, [because](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> If a class defines mutable objects and implements an `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since the implementation of hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want isophorphic graphs to have the same hash() value?  If so does this help you with the question? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization

Comment: @Aric If I have to implement it myself, then yes, I do want isomorphic graph to have the same `__hash__()` value. However, graph canonization may be overkill. What I had in mind was to get the [ordered degree sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_sequence#Degree_sequence), then to hash it. Doing so, non-isomorphic graphs could have the same hash, but isomorphic graphs could not have different hash. But before starting to do that, I first hope that someone has already done it somewhere :)

Comment: If you can find a way to make a unique integer out of the degree sequence you could use that as a hash() function.

Comment: @Aric As I understand it, the integer needs not be unique. In fact, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4005412/1661473), it could just `return 0` (but this would give poor performances). What I had in mind was to, say, put the ordered degree sequence in a tuple, then call the `__hash()__` function of that tuple. But again, my most important question is: "Are these capabilities already implemented somewhere?"

Comment: It's a pretty specific use case so maybe nobody has done exactly that.  I suggested an answer with a code example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of subclassing a networkx Graph and adding a **eq** and **hash** function as you describe.  I'm not sure if it solves your problem but should be a start.

```
import networkx as nx

class myGraph(nx.Graph):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return nx.is_isomorphic(self, other)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.degree().values())))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    G1 = myGraph([(1,2)])
    G2 = myGraph([(2,3)])
    G3 = myGraph([(1,2),(2,3)])
    print G1.__hash__(), G1.edges()
    print G2.__hash__(), G2.edges()
    print G3.__hash__(), G3.edges()
    print G1 == G2
    print G1 == G3
    graphs = {}
    graphs[G1] = 'G1'
    graphs[G2] = 'G2'
    graphs[G3] = 'G3'
    print graphs.items()
```

Outputs something like:

```
3713081631935493181 [(1, 2)]
3713081631935493181 [(2, 3)]
2528504235175490287 [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
True
False
[(<__main__.myGraph object at 0xe47a90>, 'G2'), (<__main__.myGraph object at 0x1643250>, 'G3')]
[aric@hamerkop tmp]$ python gc.py 
3713081631935493181 [(1, 2)]
3713081631935493181 [(2, 3)]
2528504235175490287 [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
True
False
[(<__main__.myGraph object at 0x1fefad0>, 'G2'), (<__main__.myGraph object at 0x27ea290>, 'G3')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will probably end up doing something like that. If someone has a similar problem, I recommend to call `freeze` on your `myGraph` objects (hence making them immutable) before using them as keys.

Comment: @user1661473 did you manage to find an hash function such that it gives the same hash if two graph are isomorphic? I'm having a similar problem.