# Implementing __eq__ via __hash__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Reading [How to implement a good __hash__ function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005318/how-to-implement-a-good-hash-function-in-python) - can I not write **eq** as

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and hash(other) == hash(self)

def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.firstfield, self.secondfield, totuple(self.thirdfield)))
```

? Of course I am going to implement `__hash__(self)` as well. I have rather clearly defined class members. I am going to turn them all into tuples and make a total tuple out of those and hash that.

Comment: Sure, if the equality of your class is covered by your `__hash__` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, a hash function will have collisions.  If you define equality in terms of a hash, you're running the risk of entirely dissimilar items comparing as equal, simply because they ended up with the same hash code.  The only way to avoid this would be if your class only had a small, fixed number of possible instances, and you somehow ensured that each one of those had a distinct hash.  If your class is simple enough for that to be practical, then it is almost certainly simple enough for you to just compare instance variables to determine equality directly.  Your `__hash__()` implementation would have to examine all the instance variables anyway, in order to calculate a meaningful hash.

Comment: That is kind of my point: My `__hash(self)__` needs to consider all the relevant fields of my class. Why should I reimplement that for equality again?

Comment: Because it is unlikely that your ``__hash__`` is capable of considering all of the relevant fields in such a way that it guarantees unequal values for unequal objects.  Does your object contain more than one int field?  It's impossible to combine two arbitrary ints into a single hash code without collision.  Does it contain even a single string field?  A str has vastly more possible values than an int can distinguish.

Comment: Well I know, that I would not be able to just add the integers or something like that. I added to the question what I was planning to do.

Comment: @Make42: `tuple.__hash__` isn't collision-free either, so that's not going to work.

Comment: @user2357112: So what is `__hash__` good for - just for hashtables, hash-based collection (like dictionary) and a "likelihood to be the same"?

Comment: @Make42: It's basically just for dicts and sets.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you **can** define `__eq__` and `__ne__` the way you have in your example, but unless you also explicitly define `__hash__`, you will get a `TypeError: unhashable type` exception any time you try to compare equality between two objects of that type.

Since you're defining some semblance of **value** to your object by defining an `__eq__` method, a more important question is what do you consider the **value** of your object to be?  By looking at your code, your answer to  that is, "the value of this object is it's hash".  Without knowing the contents of your `__hash__` method, it's impossible to evaluate the quality or validity of your `__eq__` method.