# Hashing repr of object instead of tuple of attributes

Tags: python-2.7, hash

A common way of overriding the `__hash__()` method for custom objects is to make a tuple `t` with the object attributes and apply `return hash(t)`, As described in this  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005318/how-to-implement-a-good-hash-function-in-python).

I have a program doing this, and after running cProfile, i've observed that this approach is the bottleneck of my program. I've made the following test and got the result:

```
>>> t1 = tm.Timer(setup="x = str((10,12))", stmt="hash(x)")
>>> t2 = tm.Timer(setup="x = (10,12)", stmt="hash(x)")
>>> min(t1.repeat(100)), min(t2.repeat(100))
(0.04663395881652832, 0.05523419380187988)
```

From which i conclude that using an string on the hash function is faster than 
using a tuple. Given that i've made the `__repr__()` implementation unique for every object of my class, i think that shouldn't be any problems.Before changing my program, is there any possible problem with this approach(or my test metodology)?

Comment: Shouldn't you include the string creation and the tuple creation in your benchmark?

Comment: In my case not. The tuple/string are created only once, and the hash function is executed with them many times.

Comment: If the string/tuple isn't changing, so the hash will have the same result. Why do you need to call it again and again?