# How to deduplicate dictionary in Python? Is there any method to override hashCode of some class like Java?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash

```
elements = [
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},
{'a' : 2, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},
{'a' : 2, 'b' : 3, 'c': 3},
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},
{'a' : 2, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},
{'a' : 2, 'b' : 2},
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3, 'd' : 4},
{'v' : [1,2,3]}
]
```

Given above `list` of `dict` in Python, how to deduplicate to the following collection(**order doesn't matter**) **efficiently**

```
result = [
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},
{'a' : 2, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},
{'a' : 2, 'b' : 3, 'c': 3},
{'a' : 2, 'b' : 2},
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3, 'd' : 4},
{'v' : [1,2,3]}
]
```

The naive method is to use `set`, however `dict` in Python is unhashable. Right now, my solution is to serialize `dict` to `String` like `json` format (since `dict` has no order, two different strings can correspond to same dict. I have to keep some order). However this method has too high time complexity.

My Questions:

1. How to efficiently deduplicate dictionary in Python?
2. More generally, is there any method to override a class's hashCode like Java to use `set` or  `dict`?

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005318/how-to-implement-a-good-hash-function-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your toy example with few data you can use the `repr` of the inner dictionaries as key for a new dictionary, then collect all the values:

```
elements = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},             {'a' : 2, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},
            {'a' : 2, 'b' : 3, 'c': 3},             {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},
            {'a' : 2, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3},             {'a' : 2, 'b' : 2},
            {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3, 'd' : 4},    {'v' : [1,2,3]}]

kv = {repr(inner):inner for inner in elements}
elements = list(kv.values())

print(elements)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}, 
 {'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'v': [1, 2, 3]}]
```

If you check the `id()` of your inner dictionaries you'll see the last one survives.