# Which is a better hash function and why: hash((int1, int2, int3)) or hash(int1 + int2 + int3)

Tags: python, hash

Curious and want to be a better programmer.  If this has already been asked, I apologize--I couldn't find anything similar online.

Comment: What constitutes "better" in your mind?

Comment: @blhsing  Actually, in Python writing the manual hash function isn't really good, but for understanding the principle it's okay.

Comment: "I apologize--I couldn't find anything similar online." The *first* thing I thought of trying was to put `python how to write a hash function` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+how+to+write+a+hash+function), and the first result I got was [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005318/how-to-implement-a-good-hash-function-in-python), which is another duplicate of one of the duplicates you were linked. What exactly did you try instead?